# How to add Custom Resource Definition for ManagedCertificate in GCP Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to add an SSL certificate to my GCP kubernetes cluster. My domain is already pointing to the cluster's external endpoint. I'm creating an ingress and the console gives me two options. I can upload my certificate, or I can create a Google-managed certificate. I would prefer the managed certificate, but that option is greyed out and it gives me this help text:

> To create Google-managed certificates, your cluster needs to have ManagedCertificate Custom Resource Definition present.

So how do I add ManagedCertificate Custom Resource Definition to my cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you GKE cluster is version `1.17.9-gke.6300` or later, you just need to apply a CRD in the form

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: certificate-name
spec:
  domains:
    - domain-name1
    - domain-name2
```

If you create the above in a file named `certificate-name.yaml` (replacing certificate-name with what you used in the definition above), you'd simply run

`kubectl apply -f certificate-name.yaml`

Comment: domains are fixed with url lower than 63  chars, once u use cloud endpoints,it easily pass 63 chars, how would u deal with it ?